# Parsing a DTD in Java

Tags: java, dtd

While loading the Grammar for `DTD`  I got the following error:

> "unknown protocol c".

Can anyone please help on this error?

```
XMLInputSource is = new XMLInputSource(null, dtdPath, null);
        Hashtable temp = new Hashtable();

        SymbolTable st = new SymbolTable();
        DTDHandler handler = new DTDHandler();
        XMLDTDLoader loader = new XMLDTDLoader(st);
        loader.setDTDHandler(handler);
         [![enter image description here][1]][1]
        try {

            Grammar grammar = loader.loadGrammar(is);
```

Comment: could you post your error trace so that i can understand what you are trying?

Comment: XML along with DTD will also help.

Comment: i am trying to retreive elements from a dtd in a java file ..but m not able to load it

Comment: Post the all the error trace, please ! I tink is java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c wich is a bad escaping for a path starting with c. Mabey in XMLInputSource is = new XMLInputSource(null, dtdPath, null);
the dtdPath shold use // instead of /

Answer (score 0):

Protocol is a technical term for the first part of an URI/URL, like in "http:..." and in "jdbc:..." the protocols are `http` and `jdbc`respectively.

Now with your error we have `c:`. That sounds as if you gave a **file path** where an URL was expected: `file://c:/.../...`.

The class File has a toURI.

With DTDs there are PUBLIC and SYSTEM URIs too.

Comment: i added a image of the complete stack trace